# Losing custom gridview font when new page selected

Tags: asp.net

I am using this code to change the font color in a grid view for a single column depending on value:

```
       For Each row As GridViewRow In gvSearch.Rows
           If row.Cells(8).Text.Trim = "Used" Then
               row.Cells(8).CssClass = "CautionRow"
           End If
        Next
```

This code runs after the gridview databind.  However, the gridview has pages available and this code only changes the first page of the grid view.  I can resolve the problem by not allowing pages, but this is a tacky solution.  Any suggetions?

Answer (score 0):

Register `PageIndexChanging` event

```
onpageindexchanging="gvSearch_PageIndexChanging"
```

Then in event handler do your font changing logic like

```
Sub gvSearch_PageIndexChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewPageEventArgs)
{
         For Each row As GridViewRow In gvSearch.Rows
           If row.Cells(8).Text.Trim = "Used" Then
               row.Cells(8).CssClass = "CautionRow"
           End If
        Next
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work either.  The first page works fine, but subsequent pages do not.

Answer (score 0):

Actually found my own answer thanks to help from my fellow programmer.  Here's what really works:

In the style sheet (.css) add this:

```
.CautionRow {
    color: red;
}
```

... then add this to your code:

```
Protected Sub gvSearch_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViwRowEventArgs) Handles gvSearch.RowDatabound

    If e.Row.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        If e.Row.Cells(8).Text.ToString.ToLower.Trim = "used" Then
            e.Row.Cells(8).CssClass = "CautionRow"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: e.row.cells.count >1 is the key